# Ajax/Json Error: "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type" when trying to bring a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a server-side method that is called via JSON/Ajax and it returns a list. The method works perfectly fine and returns the list, however I am obviously doing something wrong with javascript since it brings up the error:

```
""A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssociationType""
```

This is my javascript:

```
function Generate() {      
        var nofm = $('#namemap').val();
        var numberV = $('#numberv').val();
        var param = '{"NameofMap":"' + nofm + '", "VillNum":"' + numberV + '"}';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'GenerateMap.aspx/AddVill',
            type: "POST",
            data: param,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            error: function (msg)
            { alert(msg.responseText); },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(Works);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Problem seems to be this: "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssociationType"

Comment: I assume that message is coming from the error alert? (if it is, your error is likely not related to javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be serializing `DataTable` or entity framework type object. it will not get serialize and return with the error you have specified.

Better to create separate class, copy rows to list of newly typed class and then serialize using `JavaScriptSerializer`